Creating folder in power automate using send http action gives access denied error
I am making a Power automate flow where I am creating a subsite. I m able to do that successfully with below link:
https://www.annajhaveri.com/sharepoint/create-a-sharepoint-online-subsite-from-power-automate-flow
Now I want to create a folder in those subsite. I am using send HTTP request to SharePoint action and using post method.
For that below are the inputs i have provided:
Site Address - Site where I have created a subsite.
Method - Post
Uri - /_api/web/folders
Headers -
Accept
application/json;odata=verbose

Content-Type
application/json;odata=verbose

Body -
{
  "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Folder" },
  "ServerRelativeUrl":"ServerRelativeURL(this is taken from parse JSON output)/testFolder"
}

For this input i am getting forbidden error. What am i doing wrong?
I have site Admin access to the sharepoint site.

Can you show us the output format of ServerRelativeUrl parameter?

I am getting server relative url parameter as below
"ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/testsite1/test56"

Is test56 your subsite name? Generally, you can create a folder "inside" a document library. So, you will have to use the ServerRelativeUrl including document library URL NOT just subsite URL.

Yes test56 is a subsite. SO first I will need to create a library on this subsite using send HTTP action right?

SharePoint by default creates one library with name Documents (Shared Documents). You can use it if you don't need any custom document library for your use case.

Try using ServerRelativeUrl parameter value as given in my answer below and let me know if it works for you.

/sites/testsite1/test56/Shared%20Documents/01_data1
this time i gave path to shared documents as above to create 01_data1 folder but it is giving me below error
Passing in an empty or null value of parameter 'strTitle'

I think you are missing document library URL part in your ServerRelativeUrl parameter to HTTP action.
When you create a site or subsite in SharePoint, it automatically creates one document library, named "Documents" with URL name as Shared Documents.
If you want to create a new folder inside this document library, try using ServerRelativeUrl parameter like:
"ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/testsite1/test56/Shared Documents/folder1"

Refer below Microsoft official documentation and other link for more information:

Working with folders and files using SharePoint REST API
Will SharePoint automatically create intermediary folders when adding a file through the REST API?


yes i have updated the path
/sites/testsite1/test56/Shared%20Documents/01_data1 this time i gave path to shared documents as above to create 01_data1 folder but it is giving me below error Passing in an empty or null value of parameter 'strTitle'
